# Compare multidimensional array with another array in PHP and get the values from the multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional array from an XML file which I want to compare with a normal array. I need to compare the [tag] name in the multidimensional array with the name in the other array and get value from the multidimensional array that belongs to the tag.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => DOCUMENT
            [type] => open
            [level] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag] => SENDERID
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 2
            [value] => TEST
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tag] => SENDERSHORTNAME
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tag] => RECIPIENTID
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 2
            [value] => VGLEE
        )
)
```

Second array which I need to compare it with the multidimensional array:

```
$compare_array = array('DOCUMENT', 'SENDERID', 'SENDERSHORTNAME', 'RECIPIENTID');
```

Now I want to check if the key from $compare_array is matched in the multidimensional array. If so, I want to grab the value from the multidimensional array and make a variable with the name from the compare_array and append the value to the variable.

I made a for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if($values[$i]['tag'] == 'SENDERID'){
        $SENDER = $values[$i]['value'];
    }
    if($values[$i]['tag'] == 'RECIPIENTID'){
        $RECIPIENTID = $values[$i]['value'];
    }
    if($values[$i]['tag'] == 'IREF'){
        $IREF = $values[$i]['value'];
    }
    if($values[$i]['tag'] == 'DOCUMENTNUMBER'){
        $DOCUMENTNUMBER = $values[$i]['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: where are your trials? you can start by using a foreach and an if

Comment: @Ghost see updated question. This is what i first made, but I think there must be a much easier way.

Comment: i don't know why would you need such thing, but, you could probably use variable variables for all intents and purposes but i'd suggest just group them by tag instead, keep them as an array but using tags as keys

Comment: @Ghost From the XML File I get 61 keys back and I need a part of the keys+values. That's why I want to make a list and compare it. If the list changes I can dynamically make a change.

Comment: it'll still work the same, if they are grouped inside an array you can just push them whenever they have the same tag, [here's what i'm suggesting](https://3v4l.org/aRo06)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, you could use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the `tag` is present in `$compare_array`

If you must make a variable with the name from the `$compare_array` and append the value to the variable you might use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) with a flag that suits your expectations.

The `value` is not present in all the example data so you might also check if that exists.

```
$compare_array = array('DOCUMENT', 'SENDERID', 'SENDERSHORTNAME', 'RECIPIENTID');
$result = array_reduce($arrays, function($carry, $item) use ($compare_array) {
    if(isset($item["value"]) && in_array($item["tag"], $compare_array, true)) {
        $carry[$item["tag"]] = $item["value"];
    }
    return $carry;
});
extract($result, EXTR_OVERWRITE);

echo $SENDERID;
echo $RECIPIENTID;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tEsg8)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I am looking for. I have to go deeper in the documentation to understand it better, but you helped me a lot with this. I want to thank all the other guys for there help.

Comment: I have one more question. My array has indexes, but in your example the array is without indexes. How can I make the same array? Do I have to unset?

Comment: If you mean the 0, 1, 2 and 3 in your original array those are still there. 0 is the first item, then 1 etc. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/RPvom) You could read about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and the indices.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
$array = []; //Complete array to be parsed.
$compare_array = array('DOCUMENT', 'SENDERID', 'SENDERSHORTNAME', 'RECIPIENTID');


foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (in_array($value["tag"], $compare_array)) {
        $$value["tag"] = $value["value"];
    }
}
```

It will traverse through array and if `tag` name matched to value `$compare_array`, then define a variable with tag name and initialize with value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using array_in() in this case, below is the sample code

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if(in_array($values[$i]['tag'],$compare_array)){
        $value = $values[$i]['value'];
    }

}
```

For reference [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)